# Implementing 4-16 decoder using BCD to decimal (4-10) decoder

Tags: digital-logic, decoder

Is it possible to implement a 4-16 decoder using BCD to decimal decoders without using enables and how can I go on doing this?

Comment: If this is a homework problem, what have you figured out so far? If not, you must have some specific part in mind, so a link to the datsheet is required. In fact it will depend on the details of the implementation.

Comment: I have reached an answer using enable property but can't find an IC with enable in the market and I need to implement it so how can I do it? and the datasheet is here http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/sdls109/sdls109.pdf

Comment: put the extra info in your original post please

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to give you the complete solution since this is clearly homework, but you can see the key *implementation* detail that I mentioned in the comment right at the top of the datasheet:

This is an old-fashioned TTL/LSTTL type of circuit where the selected output is active 'low':

[image]

So the answer  to 'is it possible' is 'yes' in this particular instance.